# How to do asynschronous IO in linux?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, io

I need to do a somewhat unorthodox operation in Linux. I have 2 hard drives attached as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. First is 1TB, the second is 4TB. I need to compare byte-by-byte the contents of the 1TB drive if they match the first 1TB of the 4TB drive (yes, I know it's weird, but there's a reason).

Now, 1TB is a lot of data. Since those are classical hard drives, the average read speed will be around 100MB/s. At that speed, reading 1TB will take 10,000 seconds or about 2h45min. Most likely closer to 3h.

If I was to do the naive "read one then read the other" approach, the total time would be about 6h. I want to do better by reading both drives at the same time. :)

Unfortunately I'm rather unfamiliar with Linux. I know all about Windows and could write such a program there before lunchtime, but Linux is a different kind of beast. Googling for "Linux async io" gives something about [AIO functions](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/~vass/linux-aio.txt) which are pretty cryptic.

Alternatively I think I could spawn two threads for reading and a third one for comparing. `mmap()` might be useful too, since it's a 64-bit machine and there's plenty of address space.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use boost asynchronous I/O on Linux with boost::asio

Answer (score 0):

> Googling for "Linux async io" gives something about AIO functions
>   which are pretty cryptic.

Here's an example.

```
// Link with '-lrt'.
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS   64
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <aio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 0x100000    // 1 MiB

int xopen(const char *path)
{
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT);
    if (fd < 0) perror(path), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return fd;
}

void *xalloc()
{
    void *mem = memalign(0x1000, BUFSIZE);
    if (!mem) perror("memalign"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return mem;
}

void xread(struct aiocb *cbp)
{
    if (aio_read(cbp) < 0) perror("aio_read"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

size_t xwait(struct aiocb *cbp)
{
    if (aio_suspend((const struct aiocb **)&cbp, 1, NULL) < 0)
        perror("aio_suspend"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (aio_error(cbp)) perror("aio_error"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    ssize_t n = aio_return(cbp);
    if (n < 0) perror("aio_return"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    cbp->aio_offset += n;   // prepare for next read
    return n;
}

size_t min(size_t a, size_t b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

main()
{
    int lt = 0, gt = 0, eq = 0; // counters for chunks A less, greater, equal B
    int fd[2] = { xopen("/dev/sda"), xopen("/dev/sdb") };
    // 2 buffer pairs: one for reading data, other holding previously read data
    char *buf[2][2] = { xalloc(), xalloc(), xalloc(), xalloc() };
    _Bool flp = 0;  // flag which buffer pair to use for reading data
    struct aiocb cb[2] =
    { { .aio_fildes = fd[0], .aio_nbytes = BUFSIZE },
      { .aio_fildes = fd[1], .aio_nbytes = BUFSIZE }
    };
    size_t n = 0;
    do
    {
        cb[0].aio_buf = buf[0][flp], cb[1].aio_buf = buf[1][flp], flp = !flp;
        xread(&cb[0]), xread(&cb[1]);
        if (n)  // Do we have previously read data to work on?
        {
            int s = memcmp(buf[0][flp], buf[1][flp], n);
            if (s < 0) ++lt; else if (s > 0) ++gt; else ++eq;
        }
    } while (n = min(xwait(&cb[0]), xwait(&cb[1])));
    close(fd[0]), close(fd[1]);
    if (eq) printf("%7d chunks of A equal to B\n", eq);
    if (lt) printf("%7d chunks of A less than B\n", lt);
    if (gt) printf("%7d chunks of A greater than B\n", gt);
    return 0;
}
```